# VS c++ Additional Include directories

Tags: visual-studio-2010

fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'header.h': No such file or directory

What is the correct syntax for locating the path? 
Is it \\Main_folder\include\ ?

Answer (score 0):

See [Macros for build commands and properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx), or click the 'edit' button and choose 'Macros', to see the correct way to address paths within your project or solution.

For `Main_Folder\Include` you probably want `$(SolutionDir)Include` or `$(ProjectDir)Include`.

Comment: Thanks sir but maybe not in macros sir, it is in project properties/Configuration properties/C/C++/Additional Include Directories

I'm confuse with this one.
My header files are in mainfolder\include but they cant locate it.
Sorry Im new to this..

Comment: Right, yes I guessed that's where you meant. From that dialog if you try to add a new path there should be a dropdown or edit button somewhere on the dialog which will then let you choose 'macros'. However I don't have VS2010 with C++ handy to look myself exactly what it is sorry. I still think `$(SolutionDir)Include` or `$(ProjectDir)Include` will work though.

Comment: %(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)\mainfolder\include
Is this right? I use this one but still no luck, $(SolutionDir)

Comment: It depends exactly what you mean by 'main folder'. The solution folder? The project folder? something else?